# How to pass an array of results in a User defined Function in Excel-VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm checking to see if there is any way to pass an array of results in an UDF.

My function is working as expected if I pass a range, for eg - `$A$2:$A$5`, but not if I make array calculations before passing the range, for eg -  `IF($A$2:$A$5 < 3, $A$2:$A$5 ,"")` with control + shift + enter.

[image]

Here's the code I'm using-

```
Public Function ReverseTextToColumns(Rg As Range, Optional D As String = " ") As String
  Dim xArr
  xArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose((Rg.Value))
  ReverseTextToColumns = Join(xArr, D)
End Function
```

I don't want to create a complicated function and just to know how to pass an array of results in an UDF.

Comment: So your `Join(xArr, D)` should result in an array?  The problems I see here are that you're the function returns a `String` - so it can never return an array and the `Join` command _Returns a string created by joining a number of substrings contained in an array._ so that can't return an array either.

Comment: Are you trying to take a range of cells and return it as a range equal in size but in reverse order?  Or are you trying to take the values from a range of cells and then return those values in reverse order as an array?

Comment: I am trying to return a concatenation of a range with a separator, like a space or a comma, with it (in this case the default is a space " "), like (1,2,3,4,5) instead of 12345 which concat function in excel would return.
So the function should return a string and not a range.

Comment: So `IF($A$2:$A$5 < 3, $A$2:$A$5 ,"")` is a formula in a range of cells on the sheet.... your code should treat it as any other range. If your array formula is returning `"",2,"",1` across cells `B2:B5 ` then the formula `=ReverseTextToColumns(B2:B5)` returns `, 2, , 1`.  I'm not seeing where the problem is.  **NB:  I can't see the picture, so  may be missing something there**.

Comment: And that is what's baffling me. I am getting a #VALUE error. While I am expecting it to give the output as "1 2 3". 

I'm not really sure why the picture is not visible. Maybe try this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHmRT.png

Comment: I've inserted the picture for you - until you get enough reputation points you can't directly insert a picture, yourself :-)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook The picture is now visible in the question.

Comment: Sorry - should have said.  The picture isn't visible due to firewalls at my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in first argument as Variant and drop the `.Value`

```
Option Explicit
Public Function ReverseTextToColumns(n As Variant, Optional D As String = " ") As String
    Dim xArr
    xArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose((n))
    ReverseTextToColumns = Join(xArr, D)
End Function
```

Worksheet:

[image: Worksheet]

Comment: Thanks!
@DarrenBartup-Cook and @QHarr. It is working when I remove `.Value`

Comment: That confused me... hadn't refreshed the screen for a while and a deleted post had the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that this condition:

```
$A$2:$A$5 < 3
```

returns `FALSE`, which means that the empty string `""` is passed into the function. This is incompatible with the type of the parameter -- `Range`; the following function:

```
Function TestRng(rng As Range) As Boolean
    TestRng = True
End Function
```

also returns `#VALUE!` when used in a formula like so:

```
=TestRng("")
```

I suggest you make the parameter of type `Variant`, and use the VBA `TypeName` function within your UDF to check whether it is actually a `Range`.

NB. What exactly are you aiming for with this condition -- `$A$2:$A$5 < 3`? What does it mean to compare a range of cells against a number?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
NB - With the condition `$A$2:$A$5 < 3` I am taking only those numbers that are less than 3 as an input to the function. Similar to how we can use `=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$10<3,$A$1:$A$10,0))` as an array function.
I just checked the `TypeName` of the parameter "Rg" when it is passed as a Variant, and it is a range - if the input to the UDF is an excel cell range (like `A1:A5`). But it is still giving the #Value error if I pass an array of results.

Comment: @ZevSpitz  I took the input to be an array formula within a cell:  `{=ReverseTextToColumns(IF($A$2:$A$5<3,$A$2:$A$5,""))}` which will work (doesn't remove blank cells though) if `Rg` is declared as a variant as you suggested, and remove `.Value` in the `Transpose` statement.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook It is working when I remove `.Value`, at least it's not giving an error. I am getting the desired result by using `TRIM` and `SUBSTITUTE` ( spaces with a comma). 
Thanks!